# Generating a digital signature with DSA

Tags: java, security, cryptography

I want a digital signature like below code:Sign[publickey, a||b].

```
Integer a;
String b,c;
a=12; b= "i am fine";
c=a+b;  
Signature DSA = Signature.getInstance(c, "SUN"); 
DSA.initSign(pvKey);
```

Comment: You need a private key to sign something. What is the problem with your code? Any errors? Does it behave differently than you want it to?

Comment: pvkey is my private key and i want to get the value of my signature store in variable via client-socket

Comment: I think my answer could point you in the right direction, but you should provide significantly more details in your original question. What output did you expect? What output did you get? Did you get an error? If so, what was it? How are you getting the value of pvKey? Don't use variable names like `a`, `b`, or `c`, instead give them descriptive names.

Answer (score 0):

`"12iamfine"` is not a valid parameter for `Signature.getInstance()`. You need to pass the name of the algorithm, not your data that you want to sign (I assume that's what `c` is...).

I've summarized the code from the following blog for generating the signature: https://compscipleslab.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/generating-verifying-digital-signatures/

```
//Create a KeyPairGenerator object for generating keys for the DSA signature algorithm.
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA", "SUN");

//Instantiate SecureRandom Object, which will act as a source of random numbers. 
//Here, we use SHA1PRNG 
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");

//Initialize the KeyPairGenerator with the key-length and the source of randomness
keyGen.initialize(1024, random);

//Generate the key-pair
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

//Collect the public & private key from the KeyPair into separate objects
PrivateKey privkey = pair.getPrivate();
PublicKey pubkey = pair.getPublic();

//Create a Signature object, you have to supply two arguments,first the algorithm 
//name & the provider. Here we use SHA1withDSA supplied by the SUN provider
Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA", "SUN");

//Initialize it with the private key before using it for signing.
dsa.initSign(privkey);

//Supply the Signature Object the data to Be Signed
BufferedInputStream bufin = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputfile));
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;

while ((len = bufin.read(buffer)) >=0) {
    dsa.update(buffer, 0, len);
}

bufin.close();

//Sign the data i.e. generate a signature for it
byte[] realSig = dsa.sign();
```